# Why does Photoshop hide all my windows but one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

Normally I use Photoshop CS 5 tabbed (one file visible at a time).  I need to tile them all so I can compare their color temperatures (thanks cheap Android camera that changes color temp and saturation *every shot*).  Window/tile... is easy enough, but it gives me square tiles for 16:9 pix. I am trying to adjust that and move them around.

I'm dragging the windows by their top bar (obviously). When I drag one near (within 20 pixels of) the *top of the workspace*, the edge of the entire workspace gets a blue margin, and the file/window gets "gray" (fades out).  Boom! It's alone in the workspace.  All the other files are hidden.  I've tried many things to bring them back, but the only thing that works is going to the Window... menu and picking *every single one*, one pulldown per file. Very clunky with 15 files.

So first, when this "Edge turned blue, document got gray, all other documents disappear" situation is inflicted upon me, how do I *get back to where I was* (all documents visible) without having to manually select 15 files?

Second, what is that feature?  And how do I actually *wield* it for productive use?

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > Workspace > Enable Floating Document Window Docking …uncheck.

What it's doing is redocking the dragged window back to being a tab. The downside of that is it then hides all the other tiles behind it.

I can find no simple way to effectively 'undo' that, without floating all windows then re-tiling. That would presumably undo any manual sort you'd done.
I never work with tiled windows, so it's not a system I'm used to any more. Last time I used it was probably back when there was no alternative.

btw, you can tile without floating into separate windows, but I don't think that will make your task any simpler.